# vba copy and paste range value when two or more conditions are satisfied into the next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and was hoping to get come clarification on a project. I've tried solving it with formulas but I need to still be able to enter information into cells and not have them filled with a lookup formula.

How I'm looking for it to preform is that if an object requires it to be shipped then the serial numbers and identifiers are copied and pasted in another table in the next blank row automatically.

Information divided into two tables

[image: table layout]

What I thought I needed was a segment in VBA that went like this:

```
    Sub CopyCat()

    If Range("J2") Like "*yes*" then
       Range("G2:I2").copy
       Range("A2:A10").end(xlup).offset(1).pasteSpecial xlpastevalues

    If Range("J3") Like "*yes*" then
      Range("G3:I3").copy
      Range("A2:A10").end(xlup).offset(1).pasteSpecial xlpastevalues

    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

It does exactly what I ask it to do when it is only the first statement, when I add the second one to check if the next row satisfies the conditions and it does, then it places it in the same resulting cell as the first statement. If both are true I need them both to be displayed in table 1.

I'd love to take this as a learning opportunity so any information or direction you can point me in would be great! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think `Range("A2:A10").end(xlup)` is equivalent to `Range("A2").end(xlup)` so will not change, but you don't want the A2 reference, you want to work up from the bottom. You will hit problems if you are going beyond A9. (Plus not sure you want nested Ifs.)

```
If Range("J2") Like "*yes*" Then
    Range("G2:I2").Copy
    Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
If Range("J3") Like "*yes*" Then
    Range("G3:I3").Copy
    Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Or to add a loop and circumvent the copy/paste you could use something like this:

```
Sub CopyCat()

Dim r As Long

For r = 2 To Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("J" & r) Like "*yes*" Then
        Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 3).Value = Range("G" & r).Resize(, 3).Value
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without VBA.

In `A2`, you can use this formula entered as an array formula with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$4,SMALL(IF($J$2:$J$4="yes",ROW($J$2:$J$4)-ROW($J$2)+1),ROWS(J$2:J2)))
```

And in `B2`, you can put this and drag down/over from `B2:D3`:

```
=INDEX(H$2:H$4,MATCH($A2,$G$2:$G$4,0))
```

[image]

Finally, to hide the errors that show when there are no more matches, you can simply wrap both above formulas in `IFERROR([formula above],"")`.

Answer (score 0):

With autofilter

```
Sub copyRange()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filterRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")       'change to sheet name containing delivery info

    With wsSource

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set filterRange = .Range("G1:K" & lastRow)
        Dim copyRange As Range
        Set copyRange = .Range("G2:K" & lastRow)
    End With

    Dim lastRowTarget As Long, nextTargetRow As Long

    With filterRange

        .AutoFilter

        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="yes"     'change field to whichever is the field in the range containing your company names

        lastRowTarget = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        nextRowTarget = lastRowTarget + 1

        Union(wsSource.Range("G2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsSource.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy wsSource.Range("A" & nextRowTarget)

        .AutoFilter

    End With

End Sub
```